# Error when trying to remove an struct from a vector

Tags: matlab, vector, struct

Im trying to remove all the structs from a vector which has a field with some value, i tried this but got "Error using  == 
Too many input arguments."

```
s1 = struct('number', 2, 'value', 3);
s2 = struct('number', 3, 'value', 4);
s3 = struct('number', 3, 'value', 5);

aT = [s1, s2, s3];
aT(aT.number == 3) = [];
```

I would like to aT to have only [s1], any help would be awesome! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) on the array of structs instead:

```
idx = (cat(1,aT.number) == 3);
result = aT(idx);
```

The use of `cat` is because the operation of accessing the struct field outputs a kind of comma separated list, which needs to be concatenated to a vector.

Comment: @MarceloBircheFerri glad I could help! I believe you did just that by choosing the answer as "accepted".